# ICS will adjust date when add to calendar base on timezone

Tags: php, wordpress, icalendar

I've downloaded a PHP script that allow me to generate downloadable ICS for a scheduled webinar. Date & time is set to WP ACF post. Also, WordPress timezone was set to America/Los_Angeles. But my timezone is based in Manila, PH.

Here's the code.

```
// ACF Date
$wdate = get_sub_field('date'); // Tuesday, June 16, 2020
$stime = get_sub_field('start_time'); // 11:00 am
$etime = get_sub_field('end_time'); // 11:30 am

// Prepare Date using date_i18n()
// Starting DateTime
$st_gmt = $wdate.' '.$stime;
$st = get_date_from_gmt($st_gmt, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date_start = date_i18n(get_option('date_format').' '.get_option('time_format'), strtotime($st));
// Output: June 16, 2020 11:00 AM

// Ending DateTime
$et_gmt = $wdate.' '.$etime;
$et = get_date_from_gmt($et_gmt, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date_end = date_i18n(get_option('date_format').' '.get_option('time_format'), strtotime($et));
// Output: June 16, 2020 11:30 AM
```

Whenever I test downloading the .ics calendar file, which it should be `June 17, 2020 2:00 AM & June 17, 2020 2:30 AM` but the output is always set to `June 16, 2020 7:00 PM & June 16, 2020 7:30 PM` since I am based from Manila, PH while the event was set to Los Angeles.

Here's the output from actual ICS file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
LOCATION:Webinar Zoom
DESCRIPTION:This is my description
DTSTART:20200616T110000Z
DTEND:20200616T113000Z
SUMMARY:This is my summary
URL;VALUE=URI:
DTSTAMP:20200603T051015Z
UID:5ed6c0375fbf6
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Question:** How can I output the ics file to match users timezone when they download the file and add to their calendar?

Comment: HI Mark, you have made a statement here.   It is better to ask a clear question.  See See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question that you have not yet explicitly asked is how the times relate.

Note first that an ics VTIMEZONE is intended for a timezone definition ie when the actual daylight saving changes are, it is not used to say that the event is in LA time.  IT should actually contain a series of daylight saving dates IF DST is relevant in that timezone. See https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-5-time-zone-component.html

A VTIMEZONE says nothing about the VEVENTS start and end times.

In this file the event DTSTART is defined in UTC time (see the Z?) of 11 am
This is the equivalent of LA at 4am and Manila at 7pm.
See Form 2 of DATETIME: 
https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-5-date-time.html
and here for time differences
https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2020&month=6&day=16&hour=11&min=0&sec=0&p1=137&p2=145

How the times appear in an application depend then on the timezone of the user and application.  The application should convert the ics event time to the users timezone.

Comment: thanks for these links. it is a big help for me to understand the whole ics formatting. i'm new to this fyi.

Comment: You are welcome.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer